# Can I execute two different functions in same v-on:change with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hi I wonder if I can set two different functions to execute in same v-on:change?

I mean:

```
<input accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" type="file" class="form-control" v-on:change="functionOne && function Two">
```

because I will declare both in methods like this:

```
 methods: {
    functionOne() {
    },
    functionTwo() {
    }
 }
```

But they will do different things, is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to organize this, is to have a function that calls both functions.

Main function thats triggered on event:

```js
methods: {
  eventChange() {
    this.functionOne();
    this.functionTwo();
  }
}
```

```html
<input .. @change="eventChange()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do  `v-on:change="functionOne(); functionTwo()">`.
You can also call `functioTwo` from `functionOne`.
make

```
v-on:change="functionOne"
```

and in method `functionOne` do

```
functionOne () {
  // function one logic here
  this.functionTwo()
}
```